# « Jardins sous la pluie » : pas d'article ?

Tags: articles, titres

Il y a une chanson célèbre de Debussy avec le titre

> Jardins sous la pluie

Ce n'est pas "des jardins" ou "les jardins", mais juste "jardins". C'est juste dans les titres que c'est permis, ou peut-on utiliser des noms pluriels sans articles dans autres contextes ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L'absence d'article défini au pluriel n'est pas réservé aux titres mais fait partie de certains usages.

- Dans des énumérations :

> Troubadours, gueux, chevaliers, bergères, fantômes et vampires sont les personnages qui constituent l'univers de légendes 
>   
>   Ci-dessus, trouvé dans [une prière d'insérer](http://www.edilivre.com/poemes-et-chansons-1e69ce6645.html#.U6goNv6OWsE).

- Dans des noms allant en couple :

  > les relations entre patrons et ouvriers
  >   les liens entre parents et enfants, entre frères et soeurs...
- Quand un nom est mis en apostrophe :

  > Femmes entendez mon message...
- Après certaines prépositions :

  > J'ai besoin de chaussures.
  >   Je suis couverte de poils de chats.
  >   Je vais acheter un kilo de pommes.
  >   La vitre a volé en éclats sous le choc.
  >   Les touristes arrivent par cars entiers.

Answer (score 2):

On rencontre aussi cette syntaxe dans les légendes de tableaux ou de photos, ou encore dans des formulations poétiques.

On utilise ainsi une phrase sans verbe pour définir un phénomène sensible où la litote laisse l'émotivité du lecteur envahir le domaine évoqué.