# L'omission des articles définis dans les listes

Tags: prépositions, articles, coordination

Je pense qu'on n'a pas besoin du deuxième «les» dans la phrase :

> Les hommes et [les] femmes aiment des pommes.

Mes questions sont :

1. Dans le langage oral, c'est plus commun de dire le deuxième «les» ici, ou c'est plus commun l'omettre ?
2. Si on veut lier deux phrases qui prendraient des articles différents, c'est permis de n'utiliser qu'un seul article ? Par exemple, j'ai lu une note qui commençait comme ça :

   > Par respect pour le concierge et locataires...

   mais c'est possible que ce n'était pas écrit par un locuteur natif.

Comment: La première partie de [cette réponse](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/11042/358)    répond en partie à ta question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - Beaucoup *d*'hommes et *de* femmes aiment les pommes, *d*'autres pas du tout.
> - En France, hommes et femmes sont majeurs à 18 ans.
> - Par respect pour *le* concierge et *les* résidents ...
> - Ils s'entendent comme chiens et chats !

L'usage courant est de mettre l'article pour chaque entité ou de n'en mettre aucun.

La note citée est compréhensible, cependant elle n'est pas vraiment audible à l'oral, tant l'oreille est habituée au balancement des *le .., les ... et la ...*, cela fait partie du rythme habituel de la conversation ou de l'écrit.

Comment: Je pense qu'il faudrait reprendre aussi la préposition. Par respect pour le concierge et pour les résidents...

Comment: @Laure Cela dépend plutôt du contexte : reprendre la préposition pour insister, pour enfoncer le clou dans une ambiance comminatoire est logique ; mais s'il s'agit de suggérer, d'évoquer une situation, la reprendre alourdi le phrasé.

Answer (score 2):

A noter qu'il n'est pas impossible d'introduire avec un seul article des éléments mélangeant le singulier et le pluriel. Le singulier est utilisable lorsqu'il n'y a bien qu'un seul élément concerné de ce type. Dans le cas que tu cites, on pourrait avoir :

> Par respect pour **les concierge et locataires**... *(en prenant bien soin de conserver concierge au singulier)*

On pourrait d'ailleurs également grouper l'article avec deux objets singuliers :

> Les mari et femme […] ne peuvent vendre […] les biens dotaux de la femme, au préjudice d'icelle   ([Article](http://books.google.fr/books?id=amIwAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA432&lpg=PA432&dq=%22les+mari+et+femme%22&source=bl&ots=4qRrZ3nmCh&sig=YygeFnPhiZGU2HycsjkWUEAIZyU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BEi-U_WbI4SS7Ab62IGoCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22les%20mari%20et%20femme%22&f=false) de la [coutume d'Auvergne](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coutume_d%27Auvergne), version du début du XIX<sup>e</sup> s.)
>
> Les mari et femme seront alors automatiquement placés sous le régime de la communauté de biens réduite aux acquêts   ([*Le Figaro Madame*, 2014](http://madame.lefigaro.fr/societe/10-mariages-francais-avec-separation-de-biens-040314-829354))
>
> L'enfant, à tout âge, doit honneur et respect à ses père et mère.  ([Code civil français](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do?idSectionTA=LEGISCTA000006136194&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070721))
>
> Cependant il planta un arbre à l'ouest de la maison de ses père et mère  ([François Noiret, *Le mythe d'Ibonia, le grand Prince*](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Wcvs2hUyxwkC&pg=PA263&dq=%22ses+p%C3%A8re+et+m%C3%A8re%22#v=onepage&q=%22ses%20p%C3%A8re%20et%20m%C3%A8re%22&f=false))

Ca sonne très bien et ça évite la répétition de l'article.

Certains n'aiment toutefois pas cette formule. Gabriel Peignot la recense dans son [*Petit dictionnaire des locutions vicieuses* (1868)](http://books.google.fr/books?id=dWFKAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA151&dq=%22ses+p%C3%A8re+et+m%C3%A8re%22#v=onepage&q=%22ses%20p%C3%A8re%20et%20m%C3%A8re%22&f=false) comme « guère usité[e] qu'au barreau ». [*Les Omnibus du langage*](http://books.google.fr/books?id=SyEoAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA52&dq=%22ses+p%C3%A8re+et+m%C3%A8re%22#v=onepage&q=%22ses%20p%C3%A8re%20et%20m%C3%A8re%22&f=false) (1833) la considère comme « condamné[e] par tous les grammairiens ».

Comment: Ça ne me parait pas naturel. Aurais-tu ces citations avec de tels examples ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Fais une recherche web sur la chaine *"les mari et femme"*, le nombre et la pertinence des résultats t'en convaincra je suppose.

Comment: Exactement [0 occurences](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=les+mari+et+femme%2Cles+maris+et+les+femmes%2Cle+mari+et+la+femme%2Cmaris+et+femmes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cles%20maris%20et%20les%20femmes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cle%20mari%20et%20la%20femme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmaris%20et%20femmes%3B%2Cc0) sur Google ngrams. (Et 39 résultats sur le web ne changent rien, c'est dans des proportions d'erreurs de frappe.)

Comment: Parmi les premiers résultats, sans fouiller le reste en détail, je vois un [procès verbal de la chambre des députés](http://books.google.fr/books?id=YTAwAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA332&lpg=RA1-PA332&dq=%22les+mari+et+femme%22&source=bl&ots=ToJ3vj22K9&sig=QnZlxcc7Czp5DJb7DXBZU-_AmhQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=TzG9U-7kO6eL7Aae_oDICQ&ved=0CE8Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22les%20mari%20et%20femme%22&f=false), un extrait de [testament](http://www.chateauxetjardins.com/ambleville/amblevilleInventaire/archives/testamentAntoineLABBE.html), ...

Comment: ...  un [cours de droit](http://www.cours-de-droit.net/droit-de-la-famille/droit-de-la-famille,a3485617.html), ça m'a semblé pas mal, étant donné que cela ne teste pas la validité du raisonnement sur le genre de l'article, mais seulement les occurrences d'UN exemple arbitraire... ça m'a semblé déjà pas mal.

Comment: S'il faut prendre un autre exemple, il y a plein de google books et de documents juridiques qui ressortent pour *"ses père et mère"* (mais effectivement rien dans ngram, je ne sais pas pourquoi)

Comment: Il s'agit probablement d'éviter l'ambiguïté du mot « parents ». Une convention du langage juridique, j'imagine.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Pas spécifiquement du language juridique. C'est du langage soutenu, peut-être un peu vieilli, mais ça n'a rien de jargonnesque.